# the Series to be divergent and to be convergent $\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n}e^{i(3n-1)\theta }}{\ln(n)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Determine the $ \theta $ values ​​for the Series to be divergent and to be convergent,
the series is:

$$\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n}e^{i(3n-1)\theta }}{\ln(n)}$$

Steps:

I'm not sure but I get that it always converges no matter what value it takes,
taking, $(-1)^{n} = e^{-i\pi n}$ and replacing in the series then apply the criterion of the reason opting for the following.

$$\left | \frac{z_{n+1}}{z_{n}} \right | = \left | e^{i(3\theta -\pi )} \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)} \right | $$

when n tends to infinity all that tends to $0$ and since $0 <1$ then it converges, therefore it converges for all theta no matter what it is, would my answer be right?

Comment: all that does *not* tend to zero, it tends to one. Regardless of whether or not your conclusion is right, your solution is wrong

Comment: @FShrike you're right everything tends to 1 so I can't conclude anything, any idea what I could use?

Comment: You can try and think about the alternating series test. This series will never absolutely converge, only ever conditionally.

Comment: Dirichlet's test should be useful  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) p.s. for $\theta=\pi$ the general term has that form: $\frac{e^{i\pi(4n+1)}}{\ln(n)}=\frac{-1}{\ln(n)}$ that diverges.

Comment: Some simplifications might be useful: the series converges for exactly the same $\theta$ as where $e^{i\theta}$ times the series converges. And if $\phi = 3\theta$, and you can figure out for which $\phi$ the resultant series in $\phi$ converges, then that also tells you for which $\theta$ this series converges.